# The "after" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, ambiguous-tags, burninate-request

I have encountered the tag [after](/questions/tagged/after). From looking at the list of questions using it, it seems to have no real use or standard meaning. Should it be removed?

BTW, is this the right place to come to for this?

Comment: Yes, this is the right place. Adding the `burninate-request` tag in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: This is definitely the right place to come with this question. You might be interested in [tag:burninate-request]

Comment: I'll keep the burninata-request in mind for next time - thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: The mighty Trogdor lives!

Comment: While you're at it, might want to burninate [tag:before] as well.

Comment: @bolt also burninated!

Comment: I wanted to make a joke about `[during]`, but it turns out that a `[now]` tag [actually exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/now).

Comment: @pop actually, now looks .. shockingly enough .. consistently used in a way that before and after were not. Leaving it for *now*. GET IT? OMG LOOOL

Comment: Now burninate `[Comic-Sans]`.

Comment: The irony of reading `Now burninate [Comic-Sans]. – Won't` hasn't escaped me.

Comment: Jeff Atwood still has the super-sekrit tag burning tools.  I WANT MY OWN TROGDOR!